# Managing internal 3rd Party Dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, projects-and-solutions, dependency-management

We have a lot of different solutions/projects which are managed by different teams. Our solution needs to reference several projects that another team owns. We don't want to add these dependencies as project references because we do not intend on modifying that code, we just want to use it. Also we already have quite a bit of projects in our solution and don't want to add a bunch more since it will slow down Visual Studio. So we are building these projects in a separate solution and adding them as file references to our solution.

My question is, how do people manage these types of dependencies? Should I just have some automated process what looks for changes to those projects, builds them and checks the dlls into our source control, after which we treat them like other 3rd party dependencies? Is there a recommended way of doing this?

Comment: Aren't "internal" and "3rd party" orthogonal terms?  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution, although it may not necessarily be what you are looking for, is to have each dependent sub-system perform a release.  This release could be in the form of a MSI install, or just a network share of assemblies.  When a significant change is made, that team could let you know, and you could run the install or a script to copy the files.

Once you got the release, you could put them into the GAC, that way you would not have to worry about copying them to your project bin folders.

Another solution, assuming you are using a build server or continuous integration of some kind, is to have a post build step or process stage the files.  Than at any given moment, the developers of the other teams could grab the new files , or have a script or bat file pull them down locally.

EDIT - ANOTHER SOLUTION
It might be best to ask why do you have these dependencies?  Do you really need them locally when building your part of the application?  Could you mock out the dependencies in your solution, allowing you to code, build, and run unit tests?  The the actual application would wire these up in your DEV/Test/Prod environments.  Keeping your solution decoupled and dependent free may be a better solution for the individual team.  Leave the integration and coupling when the application runs in a real setting.

Comment: THe first solution is what we are using currently. I dont like this one because team members don't always let you know and you end up using outdated version of the dll. 


The CI solution is what we are currently considering, but we were thinking of having the CI build these dependencies and commit them into the version control so that if a developer gets latest he will automatically get them.

Comment: I have seen teams commit binaries to source control in this way before.  It does work.  Typically though, committing binaries into SOURCE control is not a best practice.

Answer (score 1):

(<sup>Not a *complete* answer, but still:</sup>)
Any delivery is better stored in a file/binary repository, as opposed to a VCS used to manage *sources* history.

We prefer managing those deliveries in a repo like **[Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/)**, and we are using **[maven](http://maven.apache.org/)** to get back the right dependencies.
Even if those tools can be more Java-oriented, Nexus can store anything, and maven is only there to read the `pom.xml` of each artifact and compute the right dependencies.